# How to use the autocompletion of enumerate in latexing (sublime text)

Tags: auto-completion, sublime-text, keyboard

When I write

```
\begin{enumerate}
```

sublime text does not auto complete it to

```
\begin{enumerate} \item \end{enumerate}
```

like I would expect. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 19):

If you type `enum` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> you will get this:

[image]

Similarly type `item` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get

[image]

To put a new `\item` press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of line

[image]

For a quick view of these short cuts Press `Tools` and then `Snippets` (`Cntrl+L`, `Cntrl+S`) to get

[image]

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine... I had no idea about that shortcut! Thank you! :-)

Comment: Are you not using WinEdt as your editor anymore?

Comment: @karlkoeller I do but reduced the usage as I started learning  other editors (mainly emacs). But winedt always when on windoze!. :)

Answer (score 5):

Type `begin` (without the `\`), then push <kbd>TAB</kbd>. This will complete the environment so you will see

```
\begin{env}

\end{env}
```

and the cursor will be highlighting both `env`s. You can then type `enumerate`, which will fill `enumerate` into both `env` spots, and add an `item` in the middle:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Unfortunately, it seems there is a bug that the `\` before `item` is not added automatically. The same works for `itemize`.